# How to display a date without hour, minutes, and seconds?

Tags: datetime

I have created content type and installed [Automatic Entity Label](https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_entitylabel) and generated the auto label using field tokens of:

1. field_id
2. field_DOB
3. field_Gender

After saving the content *DOB format* is displaying with time stamp           *56u **2015-10-13 00:00:00** Male* but here I want to show only something like this *56u **2015-10-13** Male*.

I want to remove this `00:00:00`.

While creating the field DOB I have chosen the following settings but still getting the hour, minutes, and seconds. How to remove this? Any suggestion?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Steps to achieve your requirement:

1. Goto **/admin/config/regional/date-time/formats/add** link, and add Format string as explained in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

   [image]
2. Now add **Date type** and select the format you created.

   [image]
3. Finally, go to content type **Manage Display** settings and add your newly created date format.
4. At URL **/admin/structure/types/manage/page/auto_label**, add token of the DOB field with the format you created by **Browsing Available Tokens**.

   [image]

Comment: I followed the same but no luck

Comment: Let me know where u stuck.

Comment: actually i am generating auto label tittle where in i am giving token something like this [node:field_dob1] [node:field_gender]                                                                         Note: for the  field_dob1 content saved  its displaying the format which we have chosen, but in the content auto label tittle where in i am using the field_dob1 token, its not displaying the format whatever i chosen

Comment: Are you using views or any other module?

Comment: i have attached screen shot of  auto label using please take a look.....i mean whenever we save save the content the title will be generated this tittle i am generating with the help of auto label, using field tokens, so my problem is whenever content saving the generated title showing with timestamp format date. like this "56u 2015-10-13 00:00:00 Male"

Comment: Please give me link of module for auto label title generation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30251/discussion-between-kashish-and-nikhil-banait).

Comment: @kashish Click "Browse Available Tokens", you'll find one in there that uses the new date format you've just set up

Comment: @kashish increase the memory limit in PHP.ini file